# Customer created order with no shipping method

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I kind of thought this was impossible. A customer on my client's store has made an order with no shipping method, whatsoever. Like, not free shipping, just none.

I can loop through shipping methods like this:

```
    foreach($order->get_shipping_methods() as $shipping_method ){
        echo '<p><strong>Shipping Method ID:</strong> '. $shipping_method->get_method_id().'<br>
        <strong>Shipping Method name:</strong> '. $shipping_method->get_name().'<br>
        <strong>Shipping Method title:</strong> '. $shipping_method->get_method_title().'<br>
        <strong>Shipping Method Total:</strong> '. $shipping_method->get_total().'<br>
        <strong>Shipping Method Total tax:</strong> '. $shipping_method->get_total_tax().'</p><br>';
    }
```

and it's just empty. Where can I begin trying to solve that? I was so sure you couldn't place an order without a shipping method.

Comment: can you check what you get with `$order->get_shipping_methods()`?

Comment: That's precisely what I was doing in the code snippet above. It's an empty array.